# SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple, Python 2.7-OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, filter

I'm currently having an error on

```
cv2.resize()
```

function from open-cv

```
scaling = 0.4
hsize = (6 * sigma + 1), (6 * sigma + 1)# The filter size.
gaussian = gauss2D(hsize, sigma)
im = filter2(gaussian, im)# Smoothed image.
im = cv2.resize(im, scaling)
```

returns this error in the IDLE:

```
 [[ 0.14417706  0.18959087  0.2234258  ...,  0.16840368  0.15120561 0.11965712]
[ 0.19098209  0.25031347  0.29384765 ...,  0.21637971  0.19531406  0.1554829 ]
[ 0.22742296  0.29720085  0.34758183 ...,  0.24855714  0.22531588 0.1804396 ]]
im = cv2.resize(im2, scaling)
TypeError: src is not a numerical tuple
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert an image into tuple? That's not what `cv2.resize` expects as input.

Comment: Because when I'm not converting it, different error message returns which is. SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] reproducing the original error in that case? It's the second argument (specifying the destination size) that should be a tuple. I guess your `scaling` variable is not correct.

Comment: cv2.resize needs tuple in one of its args right?

Comment: Yes, the second parameter (named `dsize` in the documentation) should contain the destination size as a tuple holding width and height respectively. (Unless you're also specifying `fx` and `fy`, in which case you can leave `dsize` as `None`)

Comment: Ohhh, that's very helpful thanks for the information. I

Comment: [I2, _or] = canny(image, sigma, scaling, vert, horz)
  File "C:\Users\boy bawang\Desktop\Python\iriswm.py", line 75, in canny
    im = cv2.resize(im, scaling)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

Comment: Above is the original error

Comment: Can you suggest a correct destination size that holds width and height?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add that info there -- it's really hard to parse it out of comments. Also, show the line where you define `scaling` -- what exactly is the value?

Comment: Ohhh I'm sorry, the scaling value is 0.4, it is defined from the other function which is passed. I'm going to edit it out. Thanks!

Comment: What should I put because the documentation says that if the scaling is 0 then the computation is different?

Comment: Ohh I just figured it out but there is still an error. I converted the scaling variable into tuple but now the error returns TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: What is that 0.4 supposed to mean? That you want to reduce both width and height of the image to 40% of the original? If so, you may want to use the second alternative that I've alluded to above. Basically something like `cv2.resize(im, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)` (or assuming you want to still use the `scaling` variable, this would be `cv2.resize(im, None, fx=scaling, fy=scaling)` | Note that the `dsize` is in pixels (and as such should be a pair of integers), whereas `fx` and `fy` are scaling factors.

Comment: Ohh you are a genius thank you for this, I tried None, fx=scaling, fy=scaling